# H2 completely ignores IFEXISTS=false in jdbcUrl

Tags: java, h2, hikaricp

I've got the following code to start an H2 daemon and connect to it with Hikari:

```
// Start H2 daemon
server = Server.createTcpServer("-tcpDaemon").start();

// Connect Hikari to H2 server
HikariConfig hkConfig = new HikariConfig();
    hkConfig.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
    hkConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:h2:" + server.getURL() + "/./ghost;MODE=MySQL;IFEXISTS=false");
    ...
```

However, even though `IFEXISTS` is set to `false` in the JDBC URL, I still get the following exception during pool initialization:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Database "C:/Users/Cole/IdeaProjects/ghost2/ghost" not found, and IFEXISTS=true, so we cant auto-create it
```

I tried connecting the 'normal' way with `DriverManager` to no avail. The same exception was thrown. Is there a different, working way to configure H2 features that I don't know about, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Looks like you shouldn't have to specify, it's the default behavior http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_only_if_exists - maybe you could isolate the issue by taking the pooling out and connecting over plain jdbc. Perhaps a Hikari issue?

Comment: Yeah, I tried plain JDBC via `DriverManager`. Same error. Not sure what's happening here.

Comment: Sorry, you said that in your question. Clutching at straws, have you tried `false` in upper case? All the docs have it in upper. If not, I'm out.

Comment: I tried that as well, didn't work. Found out it's a bad error message. The answer I posted details the issue.

Comment: Good find, well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a badly-written error message. See [issue #1894](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1894) for details.

Strangely enough, this issue doesn't occur in <=1.4.197. The same exact code posted above works. As far as I can tell from [#1766](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1766), this is a security issue that has been patched.